# Android SyncAdapter: How to sync when item is deleted from server side?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

In my app user can order something and later he can cancel it also but while user trying to cancel I populate a dialogue with the list of cancel reasons which is stored in local database and synced from server using `syncadapter`. We also have admin dashboard where our admin can add or delete cancel reasons. I am able to sync newly added cancel reasons but how to tell the `syncadapter` that some of the reasons are deleted?

**How my current sync works.**
Now I have a api called `get_cancel_reasons` which I hit using `syncadapter` and I send `last_updated_at` parameter which passes when was the last time my cancel reasons got updated in local database. From the server side I compare clients `last_updated_at` to my servers `last_updated_at` field. If it is behind compared to server then I send newly added cancel reason. Now how to manage if I delete one reason from server dashboard?

**What I have tried**

Instead of deleting the reason from the server I am keeping the data and a flag which says that is inactive. But the problem is if the data changes very frequently there will be lot of unnecessary data in the server database table.

Comment: somehow like this: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunByMessage ?

Comment: @SatelliteSD that I understood but consider you deleted some item in the server db. What data should I send to client now?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. always send all cancel_reasons and remove everything from your client database that has not been received from the server. Not sure how many cancel reasons you have but if its not that many I'd just go with this one. You could use ETags and the "if-none-match" header or a similar mechanism to avoid wasting any data if nothing has changed.
2. continue with your idea to flag deleted reasons. If you're worried about wasted data on the server (how frequently are these reasons expected to change anyway?) you can delete very old cancel reasons periodically and fall back to 1. if a client sends a `last_updated_at` date past the earliest updated date in your database. Of course the client should be prepared to receive a full response rather than a change set in that case.

Check out [RFC 6578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578) which describes a very similar mechanism for efficient sync in the WebDAV protocol.